# sqlplus command not found in Jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, build, sqlplus

I am trying to execute the command "sqlplus -S ${db_user}/${db_password}@${db_host}:1521/${db_sid} @${WORKSPACE}/${FIX_VERSION}/${sql_file}" in a Jenkins build and I keep getting the error "sqlplus: command not found." I have a mac and downloaded sqlplus through homebrew. I'm not sure what I am missing (if it is potentially environment variables), or how to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating the PATH variable to include sqlplus executable location before executing your SQL plus command.

```
sh """
PATH=<SQL_PLUS_HOME>/bin:$PATH
sqlplus -version
"""
```

Comment: How do I know where my sqlplus executable file is? I downloaded it through homebrew so I'm not too sure where it lives